# How can I setup TListView with CheckBoxes in only certain columns?

Tags: delphi, listview

I'm using Delphi 2010, and I am trying to allow the user to select between 2 options per row in a TListView. With TListView, I can set the style to vsReport and enable Checkboxes, but that only gets me 1 checkbox per row. What I need is 2 checkboxes per row...specifically 1 for the 1st column and 1 for the 2nd column.

What I am trying to accomplish is very similar to the standard Windows file security dialog:
[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions for implementing something like this using TListView or even MustangPeak's [TEasyListView](http://www.mustangpeak.net/easylistview.htm)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at this
[Put a TCheckBox inside a TStringGrid in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306037/how-to-set-a-checkbox-tstringgrid-in-delphi)

**update**
The link shows how to draw checkboxes. You can do the same using TListView.OnCustomDrawItem and/or OnCustomDrawSubItem events

Comment: -1, no way, you've posted a link to absolutely different thing

Comment: The link shows how to draw checkboxes. He can do the same using TListView.OnCustomDrawItem and/or OnCustomDrawSubItem events

Comment: @deamon_x: I fail to understand how it is an "absolutely different" thing.

Comment: the windows security settings dialog uses a custom window class and the theme api much in the same way as the linked answer

Comment: @daemon_x:  Nope. The difference between a string grid and the "listbox" above, is only the grid lines. Turn them off.

Answer (score 2):

I use my own modified version of ExGridView by Roman Mochalov, and full sources for my modified version, plus a demo [here](http://cid-f5bb35ae00415bc7.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/GridView%5E_WarrenPostma.zip) (open the Demo in the Demo2 folder) showing checkboxes.

[image]