# TListView - when mouse is over an item, do not draw that blue rectangle. How?

Tags: delphi, drawing, tlistview, custom-draw

When mouse moves above TListView items, there's that blue outline (see picture). How would I remove it?

The only way I know is to do all the item drawing manually... But maybe there's an easier way? Tried HotTrack=False, doesn't help :(

[image: Item3 has this blue outline]

Comment: Why do you want to go against the platform's standard way of doing things? That blue rectangle is a very important hint to the user. It tells him what would be selected if he clicked there and then.

Comment: I use custom background color for items, and while moving mouse over the items, this background disappears.

Comment: Ah ok, good on you, you are keeping the function of it just implement it differently.

Answer (score 3):

That painting is done by the special explorer theme. That is added to the control by a call to `SetWindowTheme(Handle, 'explorer', nil)` in `TCustomListView.CreateWnd`. If you use the default theme then you will not get the hot tracking. You can make that happen by reverting the explorer window theme. For example in an interposer class:

```
type
  TListView = class(ComCtrls.TListView)
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
  end;
....    
procedure TListView.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  SetWindowTheme(Handle, nil, nil);
end;
```

Of course, you'll also lose everything else that the explorer theme adds.

So far as I can tell, there are no notification messages that allow you to suppress the explorer theme hot tracking painting.

Comment: Hmm... changing a whole control theme is a bit overkill :) I suppose I need to implement full item drawing myself then.

Comment: It looks like I don't have to reinvent the wheel, this SO question has the code to draw items: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519742/drawing-a-checkbox-in-a-tlistview In case anyone else will be looking for this :)