# From cell coordinates to Canvas pixel position on OnSelectCell event in tStringGrid in Delphi

Tags: delphi, canvas, tstringgrid

The **OnDrawCell** event gives me a "Rect" record so that I know where the real pixel coordinates are:

```
OnDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
```

On the other hand, the **OnSelectCell** only gives me the row/col coordinates.

```
OnSelectCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer; var CanSelect: Boolean);
```

How do I translate the row/col to pixel coordinates?

I need those because I need to create a ComboBox at runtime to cover the whole selected cell, but only when the cell is selected. I know how to do everything, but I do not know how to get the coordinates (right now, I am just creating the combo at 0,0 of the parent tStringGrid).

I am using Delphi7, but I think it is a general question and not related to the Delphi version.

PS: I am aware that there are plenty of commercial and freeware components that implement a combobox inside a cell, but I cannot and/or do not want to use them.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can determine cell screen coordinates using [CellRect method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomDrawGrid.CellRect)

P.S. Have you ever tried to integrate controls into StringGrid?
When you meet problems with controls (having grid as Parent) behavior, look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719454/why-dont-child-controls-of-a-tstringgrid-work-properly/11723954#11723954)

Comment: Perfectly what I was looking for. Just for future references:
myRect := (sender as TStringGrid).cellRect(aCol, aRow);

Comment: About the integrating... Not really. I am just at the beginning of writing my custom onDrawCell for example...

Comment: OK, I've added a link about possible future problems.